# How to concat multiple Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The `result` dataframe should be the combined version of three other dataframes: `dfa`, `dfb` and `dfc` and it should be:

```
     a     b    c
0  1.0   0.0    0
1    0  10.0    0
2    0     0  100
```

Unfortunately the code below produces a different result:

```
result = pd.DataFrame()
dfa = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1]})
dfb = pd.DataFrame({'b':[10]})
dfc = pd.DataFrame({'c':[100]})

for df in [dfa, dfb, dfc]:
    result = result.reindex(columns=df.columns, fill_value=0)
    result = pd.concat([result, df], ignore_index=True)

print result
```

Here is what the results is:

```
     c
0    0
1    0
2  100
```

What could be done to get the `result` needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`Index.union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.union.html) for find final columns names for `reindex`:

```
cols = dfa.columns.union(dfb.columns).union(dfc.columns)
print (cols)
Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')
```

Then in loop `reindex` and append new DataFrames to list of `DataFrames` `dfs`, which is finally [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
dfs = []
for df in [dfa, dfb, dfc]:
    result = df.reindex(columns=cols, fill_value=0)
    dfs.append(result)

result = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
print (result)
   a   b    c
0  1   0    0
1  0  10    0
2  0   0  100
```

---

If in dataframes `dfa`, `dfb` and `dfc` are not `NaN` values, you can use [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), but more general working with `NaN` is first solution:

```
result = pd.concat([dfa, dfb,dfc], ignore_index=True).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (result)
   a   b    c
0  1   0    0
1  0  10    0
2  0   0  100
```

Sample with `NaN`:

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1]})
dfb = pd.DataFrame({'b':[10]})
dfc = pd.DataFrame({'c':[np.nan]})

cols = dfa.columns.union(dfb.columns).union(dfc.columns)

dfs = []
for df in [dfa, dfb, dfc]:
    result = df.reindex(columns=cols, fill_value=0)
    dfs.append(result)

result = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
print (result)
   a   b    c
0  1   0  0.0
1  0  10  0.0
2  0   0  NaN

#data NaN are overwrite by 0
print (pd.concat([dfa, dfb,dfc], ignore_index=True).fillna(0).astype(int))
   a   b  c
0  1   0  0
1  0  10  0
2  0   0  0
```

Comment: I add second solution, maybe helpful too.

Comment: Yeah, the second solution is great! But the trick with the column.union is good to know too.

Comment: Yes, I add solution for NaN - be aware for overwritten.